# How to access item in <slot> inside v-for (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to send item from v-for to slot? In [vue.js](http://vuejs.org).

ListComponent:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in list">
    <slot></slot>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Page view:

```
<list-component :list="list">
  <span v-text="item.value"></span>    
</list-component>
```

Code `<span v-text="item.value"></span>` can't access `item` (from component's scope). Is it a way to send an `item` from component to code in  tag?

**P.S.** I know, that as a workaround I can send `$index` from component to parent view, but it's a little bit hacky

---

**UPD:** Example of my current workaround (somebody may find this useful):

Declare `index` in view's data:

```
data () {
  return {
    index: 0,
    list: [ ... ]
}
```

Add to `index` param to the view's template:

```
<list-component :list="list" :index="index">
  <span v-text="list[index].value"></span>    
</list-component>
```

Declare `index` in component's props:

```
props: {
  index: {
    type: Number
  }
}
```

Add index to `v-for`'s element:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in list" index="$index">
    <slot></slot>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is the "ListComponent" html that you posted the template for the `<list-component>' ?
It looks like you are trying to use inline template with the "Page View" you posted. I believe you need to pick one, it could be a problem mixing both.

Answer (score 3):

the bind expression is compiled in the context who define them,so:

```
v-text="item.value"
```

can not be compiled because in Page view there is no "item" defined.

maybe you can try to **change your code structure** like below:

ListComponent:

```
//content in component
<span>i am text in component,item value is:{{item.value}}</span>
<slot></slot>
```

Page view:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in list">
      <list-component :item="item"></list-component>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not an option for me (cause real code much more complicated), but thanks for the answer